# JavaScript regex: add strings (preceding & following) to the matched string

Tags: javascript, regex, string, replace

Say I have the following string in JavaScript:

```
var text = "This is Table1, and the next table is Table2"
```

I need to highlight the `Table1` and `Table2` bold in HTML by adding `<b></b>`, e.g. `<b>Table1</b>`. Making it even more difficult is the word preceding/following `Table1 or 2` varies.

```
text.replace(/Table\d+/g, "<b>Table</b>"); // how to reserve the number for Table1 or Table2 here?
```

Thanks

Comment: Is your string static? If yes then make use of a counter. Like "<b>Table" + counter + "</b>"

Comment: Go look up what _back reference_ means in regex context ...

Comment: my bad, I didn't know the term *back reference* before seeing your comment. I am no expert to regex by any means. thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do

```js
var text = "This is Table1, and the next table is Table2"

console.log(text.replace(/(Table\d+)/g, '<b>$1</b>'))
```

Comment: awesome! works beautifully! thank you :)

Comment: You may omit capturing altogether by using `.replace(/Table\d+/g, '<b>$&</b>')`